# How to remove a specific object from an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

So I'm currently making a calorie tracker. In this app, you enter the recent meal you ate, and the amount of calories in that meal. Then you press the "add" button. This button will save the data to a TableView called HistoryTableViewController. To check if the person has left a textfield blank, I have 3 "if statement". One looks like this:

```
if ([[self.amountText.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length] < 1)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"You have not entered the amount of Calories!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [amountHistory removeObjectAtIndex:0];

}
```

There is one line of code that I know is wrong which is the

```
[amountHistory removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

I don't necessarily want to remove the first object on the tableview, I just want to make sure that the item doesn't get added.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I add an object to the array at the top of the if statements:

```
 total+= self.amountText.text.intValue;
 self.totalLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", total];
NSNumber *calorieNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:self.amountText.text.intValue];
NSString *foodString = nameOfTheFood.text;
NSString *historyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Calories in %@",       calorieNumber, foodString];
[amountHistory addObject:historyString];
```

Comment: unfortunately this question doesn't make sense. You have a add button but you want to remove something from amountHistory array. What is that you want to remove?

Comment: At what point do you add the item to the array?

Comment: Have you bothered to read the spec for NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are thinking about it from the wrong angle.

Instead of adding the item to your array and then removing it if it is invalid, you should ensure the item is only added when it is valid.

So in your method you would only add the item at the end, after all validation has passed. You would add early `return`'s in your `if` statements if the any validation fails so that you don't reach the code that adds the item to the array

Comment: Ah....yeah this sounds better. Sorry I'm still trying to get into that mindset of an efficient developer. I think I'll go with this one.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your subject:

```
How to remove a specific object from an array
```

is

```
[array removeObject:obj];
```

Note, this uses the `isEqual` message on the object to determine equality. If you want specific object equality, use `removeObjectIdenticalTo:` instead.

Source: [Apple Docs on NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObject%3a)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove the last item in the array use:

```
[amountHistory removeLastObject];
```

But if your issue is that you don't want to add blank items to the array why not check if they are blank before adding them?

Answer (score -1):

You can only remove objects from an array if you are using NSMutableArray. Have a read of the [NSMutableArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)